# How can I use SetJob in win32print?

Tags: python, printing, pywin32, win32com, python-3.6

I want to clear or delete print jobs using Python.
But how can I get `JobID`?

`win32print.SetJob(hPrinter, JobID , Level , JobInfo , Command)`

How could I run this code?

```
jobs = []
for p in win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL,None, 1):
    flags, desc, name, comment = p

    pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name)
    print = list(win32print.EnumJobs(pHandle, 0, -1, 1))
    jobs.extend(print)
    SetJob(pHandle, id, 1,JOB_CONTROL_DELETE)
    #where should i get id from?
    win32print.ClosePrinter(pHandle)
```

Comment: Do you know some details about the printer (e.g. printer name)? Cause it makes no point of iterating through all installed printers and attempting to do this operation. Also you're assigning a value to `print` which is a builtin function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your code, I've managed to create a small script that deletes any print job on any (local) printer (I've tested it and it **works**).

Here it is (I've run it with *Python 3.5*):

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import win32print as wprn


def main(*argv):
    enum_flags = wprn.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL #| wprn.PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED
    printer_name = None
    printer_info_level = 1
    for printer_info in wprn.EnumPrinters(enum_flags, printer_name, printer_info_level):
        name = printer_info[2]
        #print(printer_info)
        printer_handle = wprn.OpenPrinter(name)
        job_info_level = 1
        job_info_tuple = wprn.EnumJobs(printer_handle, 0, -1, job_info_level)
        #print(type(job_info_tuple), len(job_info_tuple))
        for job_info in job_info_tuple:
            #print("\t", type(job_info), job_info, dir(job_info))
            wprn.SetJob(printer_handle, job_info["JobId"], job_info_level, job_info, wprn.JOB_CONTROL_DELETE)
        wprn.ClosePrinter(printer_handle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- What I said in my comment (about iterating over printers) still stands, but I suppose that is beyond the scope of this question
- I've improved the script a little bit:

  - Give (more) meaningful names to variables
  - Use variables instead of plain numbers to increase code readability
  - Other small corrections
  - Probably, it could use some exception handling
- The secret of the script consist of:

  - *EnumJobs* returning a *tuple* of dictionaries (where each dictionary wraps an [[MS.Docs]: JOB_INFO_1 structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145019(v=vs.85).aspx) - for `job_info_level = 1`), or (obviously) an empty tuple if there are no queued jobs for the printer
- How the information from *EnumJobs* is passed to *SetJob*:

  - The *JobID* argument (that you asked about) is `job_info["JobId"]` (check previous bullet)
  - Also notice the next 2 arguments: *Level* and *JobInfo*

Comment: I have issue in getting the remote/network printer attached, win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_NETWORK) and win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED)
both giving empty tuples, But there is a printer listing in 'Printers and Scanners' . Can please suggest how can I solve it, Thanks

Comment: @Jisson: sorry for the late response. Note that what *Printers and Scanners* contains printers/servers that were installed previously, and they might not (or no longer) exist. You can play with the flags for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/enumprinters (use the name).

Answer (score 0):

@CristiFati solution has a problem. It generates an exception when it's successful. You have to put it inside a try except block if you want to use it in your program.

I've found another better and easier solution to delete print jobs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50443807/16198594

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32607538)

Comment: What you are saying is generally true but I believe this is an exception since I've posted this on stackoverflow with a link to stackoverflow. I think copy-quoting the entire post for stackoverflows internal links is much better done and with greater effect from stackoverflows own web developers instead of "training" the users.