# I can not delete print job with python win32print

Tags: python, winapi

I use python3 with win32print like this code. It should delete all print job because TotalPages >= 1 . I think all datatype are correct.

```
import time
import win32print

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def print_job_checker():
    """
    Prints out all jobs in the print queue every 5 seconds
    """
    jobs = [1]
    while jobs:
        jobs = []
        for p in win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL,
                                         None, 1):
            flags, desc, name, comment = p

            phandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name)

            print_jobs = win32print.EnumJobs(phandle, 0, -1, 1)

            if print_jobs:
                jobs.extend(list(print_jobs))

            for job in print_jobs:

                print(job['TotalPages'])

                if(job['TotalPages'] >= 1):
                    print(type(job))
                    win32print.SetJob(phandle, job['JobId'], 1, job, win32print.JOB_CONTROL_DELETE)

            win32print.ClosePrinter(phandle)

        time.sleep(0.25)
    print ("No more jobs!")


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        print_job_checker()
```

when I run it show error like this.

> File "C:/Users/test_printer.py", line 37, in print_job_checker
>       win32print.SetJob(phandle, job['JobId'], 1, job, win32print.JOB_CONTROL_DELETE)
>
> **error: (1804, 'SetJob', 'The specified datatype is invalid.')**

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deleting and not changing job attributes, try this;

```
win32print.SetJob(phandle, job['JobId'], 0, None, win32print.JOB_CONTROL_DELETE)
```

The following parameters has changed:

Level = 0

pPrinter = None